# decrypt md5 hash function

Tags: md5

Got this question in one of tests. But still I am not able to figure this out.

You are a pentester and have been hired by a financial organization to evaluate 
the security of a web application which contains customer usernames and passwords. 
Through an vulnerability in the web application you where able to download a table which 
contains entries similar to below:
username password

jsmith 26fb49c7a06ae7cc88792de48bd94539
stevej 31edaffbaba455bc30c52681ceb1ea9d
You also find out in your reconnaissance that the database is using MD5 hashes and is not 
salted. How can you recover the plain text passwords in the file?

Comment: Rainbow table / brute force. As its impossible to decrypt hashing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MD5 is a one-way hash function and theoretically cannot be reversed.  If you know for a fact that the password hashes were not salted, then you would have to use a [rainbow table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) to seek out any possible matches.

There are numerous online tools that do this, such as [Ben Ramsey's Reverse MD5 hash lookup](http://tools.benramsey.com/md5/).